# Showing bilinearity of the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, algebras

The tensor product for vector spaces $U,V$ is the initial object in the category of bilinear functionals on $U \times V$.

Spelt out, this means there is a vector space $U \otimes V$, and a bilinear fuctional $i: U \times V \rightarrow U \otimes V$

Such that for any bilinear functional $f: U \times V \rightarrow U \rightarrow W$ to any vector space $W$

There is a unique linear map $f': U \otimes V \rightarrow W$

Such that $f=f' \circ g$

Writing $u \otimes v := i(u,v)$, this means $f(u,v)=f'(u\otimes v)$

Given all this, I don't see how we can say that $au\otimes v = u \otimes av = a(u \otimes v)$

**edit**

The comment below by Yeldarbskich shows I just missed the obvious:

$i: U \times V \rightarrow U \otimes V$  is *defined* to be bilinear, and renamed to $\otimes$; hence $au \otimes v = i(au,v)=i(u,av)=u \otimes av$

and similar for the other identities.

Comment: Use `\otimes` for $\otimes$ and `\circ` for $\circ$.

Comment: Apparently the TeX commands you normally use are nonstandard (or at least MathJax doesn't have it). You should use $\otimes$ and $\circ$.

Comment: Sorry, \otimes as Henning Makholm said, and \circ.

Comment: You said that $i:U \times V \to U \otimes V$ was BILINEAR and you then defined $u \otimes v$ to be $i(u,v)$. So by bilinearity of $i$ you can get $$ i(au,v)=i(u,av)=a \, i(u,v) $$ to get what you wanted.

Comment: @makholm: thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take the universal bilinear map $i$ and get your universal $i':U\otimes V\to U\otimes V$. This map is the identity since such a map is unique and the identity satisfies the condition. We have
$$i(au,v)=ai(u,v)=i'(au\otimes v)=ai'(u\otimes v)$$ 
so 
$$au\otimes v=a(u\otimes v)$$ 
Similarly $u\otimes av=a(u\otimes v)$, so we have a three way equality, which is exactly your last set of equations.